# Cannot get bootstrap-sass to work with webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-sass

Im following the instrtuctions on [the bootstrap-sass-loader page](https://www.omniref.com/js/npm/bootstrap-sass-loader/1.0.1)

in my package.json I got

```
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
"bootstrap-sass-loader": "^1.0.9"
```

this is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app.js'],
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: 'build/bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'eval',
  module: {
    /* used on code before it's transformed */
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'source-map'
      }
    ],
    /* used to modify code */
    loaders: [

      {test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery'},
      {test: /\.obj|\.mtl|\.html|\.dae|\.txt/, loader: "raw"},
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, loader: 'babel'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file"},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"},
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        /* order from bottom to top, so first sass, autoprefix, css and finally style */
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'autoprefixer?browsers=last 3 versions', 'sass?outputStyle=expanded']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['url?limit=8192', 'img']
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ],
    /* used to modify generated code */
    postLoader: []
  }
};
```

as far as I understand I just have to use

```
require("bootstrap-sass-loader");
```

in my `app.js` and be done. but I cannot use any bootstrap styles. what am I missing here?

Answer (score 11):

It's not straightforward but it can work without having to do json.

Start by importing boostrap-sass (installed via npm) in your main.js/ts

```
require("bootstrap-sass");
```

Or if you're using ts/ES6:

```
import "bootstrap-sass";
```

Then just import these two in the component's styles (inline or external sass/scss file in Angular 2):

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "../styles/bootstrap/bootstrap"
```

You then need to have a folder ../styles/bootstrap with the following contents:

- variables.scss: Just copy and customise from node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss
- bootstrap.scss: This is a "webpack-ified" version of the main bootstrap file:

//

```
  @import "variables"; //this is the key to easy customisation
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/normalize";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/print";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/glyphicons";

  // Core CSS
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/scaffolding";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/type";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/code";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/grid";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/tables";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/forms";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons";

  // Components
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/component-animations";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/dropdowns";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/button-groups";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/input-groups";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/navs";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/navbar";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/pagination";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/pager";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/labels";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/badges";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/jumbotron";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/thumbnails";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/alerts";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/progress-bars";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/media";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/list-group";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/panels";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-embed";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/wells";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/close";

  // Components w/ JavaScript
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/modals";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/tooltip";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/popovers";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/carousel";

  // Utility classes
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/utilities";
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-utilities";
```

Finally, the webpack config bit. This could be the loader:

```
{
      test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
      loader: "file?name=[path][name].css!sass-loader"
    }
```

And this a way to load jquery:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery"
})
```

Comment: You say: "Then just import these two in your sass/scss file". How do you include/import "your" sass/scss file?

Comment: Sorry, I realise "your" is not particularly explanatory. I've edited my answer. I meant the component's styles

Comment: I get a dozen of these `Error in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/...`
`Module not found: 'jquery' in /home...`

Answer (score 0):

It took forever to get bootstrap-sass-loader to work but I never liked it. You are much better off compiling it directly and use a js file to override boostrap variables or add new ones with [jsontosass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontosass-loader).

make sure that jquery is properly loaded

```
  resolve     : {
    alias         : {     
      // bind to modules;
      modules     : path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
    }
  },
  plugins     : [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$"                   : "jquery",
      "jQuery"              : "jquery",
      "window.jQuery"       : "jquery"
    }),
```

add in the webpack.config.js

```
var sassGlobals = require('[YourVars.json file]');
var sassVars = JSON.stringify(sassGlobals);
```

add to the loaders

```
  { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass","jsontosass?" + sassVars]},
  { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
  { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
  { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
```

in your app.scss you do the following imports

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-sprockets.scss";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
```

and finally in your app.js you add the following (modules is aliased to node_modules).

```
/**
 * initializes bootstrap
 */
require("modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js");
require("./app.scss");
```